# .Net C# Mvc Db connection (Db from other people)

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to .Net and especially new Mvc.

I have a database from a senior in his own project that I must connect using the connection string, which I can connect successfully in web config of traditional web forms.

But now I want to connect that database in Mvc. I dont have local db in my pc but can access it through the id and password in the previous project as mentioned.

So is there any ways to connect and use it in Mvc? I would like to know exactly the source code that i need to put in which part. I am totally new and still blur after reading so many tutorials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? In MVC also there is a connection string. If you want to generate classes from DataBase then you can use EntityFramework. I think only with the tool EntityFramework it can create for you the connectionSttring. [Generate Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx). I hope it will help you.